# Laravel JSON to Array Casting

Tags: json, laravel, laravel-5.3

is there any reason eloquent `$casts` wouldnt be working?

I am storing json, json column type, and

```
protected $casts = [
    'fields' => 'array'
];
```

But..

```
\App\Lead::find(1)->fields
```

still returns json

```
"{"first_name":"Brian","last_name":"Dillingham","email":"brian@gmail.com"}"
```

Doesn't even work when I mutate

```
public function getFieldsAttribute($value)
{
    return json_decode($value, true);
}
```

But works when I

```
dd(json_decode(\App\Lead::find(1)->fields, true));
```

Comment: I think its because I am manually storing the json in a text field, sorry cant delete the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just type cast it from your mutator function:

```
public function getFieldsAttribute($value)
{
    return (array) json_decode($value, true);
}
```